# Find a list by its name C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a series of lists, I want to create a method which will find a list by its name and return the list. The lists are stored within the class itself.

```
    public void AddCord(string cord, string listName)
    {
        List<String> myShip;
        myShip = findListByName(listName);
        myShip.Add(cord);
    }
```

Please keep the code to the simplest methods..

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Perhaps you should show how the lists are stored and where the name comes into this? Is it the name of the list, or the name of a ship in the list, or what, that you're searching for? Have you tried implementing it already? If so, what did that code look like?

Comment: Hi, Sorry if i wasn't clear

The lists are stored in the class, then constructed within the class like so: 

class Battleship
    {
        //Attributes, Player Ships
        private List<string> _playerCarrierA;
        private List<string> _playerDestroyerA;

       public Battleship()
        {
            _playerCarrierA = new List<String>();
            _playerDestroyerA = new List<String>();
        }

There are a lot more lists than that, basically I want a method to retrieve the list by its name, then add a string to that list. 

I have tried many methods, none have been successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Create global dictionary of lists
Dictionary<string, List<string> dictionaryOfLists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>();

//Get and create lists from a single method
public List<string> FindListByName(string stringListName)
{
    //If the list we want does not exist yet we can create a blank one
    if (!dictionaryOfLists.ContainsKey(stringListName))
        dictionaryOfLists.Add(stringListName, new List<string>());

    //Return the requested list
    return dictionaryOfLists[stringListName];
}
```

Comment: Oh brilliant, that might just work :D thanks ill try it out now

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myRecords=new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

if(!myRecords.ContainsKey("abc"))
{
    List<string> abcList=new List<string>();
    myRecords.Add("abc", abcList);
}
else 
    myRecords.["abc"].Add("a");
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, never come across dictionary before :)

Answer (score -1):

This is my answer, a little more fun one solution in my eyes : D

```
class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    static List<object> superlist;

    public string name;

    ~MyList() {
        if (superlist != null)
        superlist.Remove(this);
    }

    public MyList(string name)
        : base() {
        init(name);
    }

    public MyList(string name, int cap)
        : base(cap) {
        init(name);
    }

    public MyList(string name, IEnumerable<T> IE)
        : base(IE) {
        init(name);
    }

    void init(string name) {
        if (superlist == null)
            superlist = new List<object>();

        this.name = name;
        superlist.Add(this);
    }

    public static void AddToListByName(T add, string listName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < superlist.Count; i++) {
            if (superlist[i].GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] == add.GetType() && ((MyList<T>)(superlist[i])).name == listName) {
                ((MyList<T>)(superlist[i])).Add(add);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("could not find the list");
    }

}
```

and now you can use it easily and cleanly in your code

```
        MyList<string> a = new MyList<string>("a");
        MyList<string> b = new MyList<string>("b");

        a.Add("normal add to list a");

        MyList<string>.AddToListByName("hello add to a", "a");
        MyList<string>.AddToListByName("hello add to b", "b");
```

Comment: I think using a static approach is a huge code smell. And having a destructor *really* raises red flags...